# Feeding array (shape with rank 1) to TensorFlow tf.case

Tags: python, tensorflow

Following this example from the `tf.case` documentation:

```
def f1(): return tf.constant(17)
def f2(): return tf.constant(23)
def f3(): return tf.constant(-1)
r = tf.case({tf.less(x, y): f1, tf.greater(x, z): f2},
            default=f3, exclusive=True)
```

I want to do the same, but allow to use a feed_dict as input, illustrated by this snipped:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None])
z = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None])
def f1(): return tf.constant(17)
def f2(): return tf.constant(23)
def f3(): return tf.constant(-1)
r = tf.case({tf.less(x, y): f1, tf.greater(x, z): f2},
            default=f3, exclusive=True)
print(sess.run(r, feed_dict={x: [0, 1, 2, 3], y: [1, 1, 1, 1], z: [2, 2, 2, 2]}))
# result should be [17, -1, -1, 23]
```

So, basically I want to feed three `int`-arrays of equal length and receive an array of `int`-values containing either 17, 23, or -1. Unfortunately, there code above gives and error:

> ValueError: Shape must be rank 0 but is rank 1 for 'case/cond/Switch' (op: 'Switch') with input shapes: [?], [?].

I understand, that `tf.case` requires boolean scalar tensor input values but is there any way to achieve what I want? I also tried `tf.cond` without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`tf.where`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/where) for that, for example like this ([broadcasting support for `tf.where` seems to be on its way](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/9284), but not there yet as far as I can tell, so you have to make sure all arguments have the same size with a vector of ones, or [`tf.fill`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/fill), [`tf.tile`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/tile)...).

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None])
    y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None])
    z = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None])
    ones = tf.ones_like(x)
    r = tf.where(x < y, 17 * ones, tf.where(x > z, 23 * ones, -ones))
    print(sess.run(r, feed_dict={x: [0, 1, 2, 3], y: [1, 1, 1, 1], z: [2, 2, 2, 2]}))
    # [17. -1. -1. 23.]
```

Comment: Thank you, I had tried tf.where before but did not recognize the missing broadcasting support (trying tf.constant instead of tf.ones_like).